# Make operations in $addField aggregation in Spring Data MongoDb 3.0.0

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-repositories

I tried different ways to make aggregation with spring Data Mongo Db but none of them worked for my purpose : add a field dynamically with operations.

Here is my mongoDB aggregation (it works, I checked) :

```
db.getCollection("AquilaMaterial").aggregate(
[
    { 
        "$match" : { 
            "a.date" : { 
                "$gte" : ISODate("2021-08-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "$lte" : ISODate("2021-08-02T00:00:00.000+0000")
            }, 
            "a.line" : "TEST"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$addFields" : { 
            "time_dist" : { 
                "$abs" : [
                    { 
                        "$subtract" : [
                            "$a.date", 
                            ISODate("2021-08-01T11:52:00.000+0000")
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$sort" : { 
            "time_dist" : 1.0
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$limit" : 20.0
    }, 
    { 
        "$project" : { 
            "time_dist" : 0.0
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$sort" : { 
            "a.date" : 1.0
        }
    }
])
```

So, first thing, i wrote this code but I got javaHeapSpace after a very long time waiting :

```
@Aggregation(
    pipeline = "{ '$match' : { 'a.date' : { '$gte' : ?1, '$lte' : ?2}, 'a.line' : ?3"
        + "}}, { '$addFields' : { 'time_dist' : {'$abs'[{ '$subtract' : ['$a.date', ?0]}]}}}, {'$sort' : { "
        + "'time_dist' : 1}},{'$limit' : _sampleSize},{ '$project' : {'time_dist' : 0}},{'$sort' : {'a.date' : 1}}")
AggregationResults<MaterialEntity> findMaterialsInSequenceDate(final Date _date, final Date _dateFrom, final Date _dateTo,
    String _line, int _sampleSize);
```

The I tried to write it manually but I can't figure out how to use properly the addFieldsOperation in my case. It does something like below :

```
public List<MaterialEntity> findMaterialsInSequenceDate(final Date _date, final Date _dateFrom, final Date _dateTo,
    final String _line, final int _sampleSize) {

    MatchOperation matchDateOp = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("metalUnit.cuttingDate").gte(_dateFrom).lte(_dateTo));
    MatchOperation matchLineOp = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("metalUnit.metalUnitReference.step.stepName").is(_line));
    AddFieldsOperation addFieldOp = Aggregation.addFields().addField("time_dist")
        .withValueOf(**DO_SOMETHING**).build();
    SortOperation sortOp = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "time_dist");
    LimitOperation limitOp = Aggregation.limit(_sampleSize);
    SortOperation sortOp2 = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "a.date");
    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchDateOp, matchLineOp, addFieldOp, sortOp, limitOp, sortOp2);

    AggregationResults<MaterialEntity> aggResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "Material",
        MaterialEntity.class);
    return aggResults.getMappedResults();
}
```

this code works without the addedField (and the sort associated with it) but the data I get is not good of course...

Comment: When this is executed, you can see the excuted aggregation in the console... have you compared both?

Answer (score 0):

This works but i am afraid dates are biased because not using the proper time zone. Any idea to improve this ?
public List findMaterialsInSequenceDate(final Date _date, final Date _dateFrom, final Date _dateTo,
final String _line, final int _sampleSize) {

```
    MatchOperation matchDateOp = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("a.date").gte(_dateFrom).lte(_dateTo));
    MatchOperation matchLineOp = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("a.line").is(_line));
    AddFieldsOperation addFieldDateTemp = Aggregation.addFields().addField("timeStampTemp").withValue(_date).build();
    AddFieldsOperation addFieldOp = Aggregation.addFields().addField("time_dist")
        .withValueOf(ArithmeticOperators.Abs.absoluteValueOf(Subtract.valueOf("timeStampTemp").subtract("a.date"))).build();
    SortOperation sortOp = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "time_dist");
    LimitOperation limitOp = Aggregation.limit(_sampleSize);
    SortOperation sortOp2 = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "metalUnit.cuttingDate");
    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchDateOp, matchLineOp, addFieldDateTemp, addFieldOp, sortOp, limitOp, sortOp2);

    AggregationResults<MaterialEntity> aggResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "Material",
        MaterialEntity.class);
    return aggResults.getMappedResults();
```